# publish npm lib angular

Tags: angular, npm, publish

I have a problem when trying to run the following npm command:

npm publish --access public

I'm trying to upload an angular lib

I already logged in, but even so it keeps giving this error, I don't know what else to do.

[image: 1]

I already tried to log in, and nothing